# Nvidia display settings are not available server 2019

Tags: nvidia

I am currently running google VPS Cloud with Tesla K80, I did install the last driver from `NVIDIA` But I can't manage to make it run and getting the following error :

```
Nvidia display settings are not available
```

Kindly guide me how to fix this issue. Thanks